# Call deployed smart contract function from new smart contract via bytes.?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, abi, smartcontracts

As per solidity documents [page](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#function-selector-and-argument-encoding)

I Created and deployed following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract Foo {
  uint public result;
  function bar(bytes3[2]) public pure {}
  function baz(uint32 x, bool y) public pure returns (bool r) { result = x; return y; }
  function sam(bytes, bool, uint[]) public pure {}
}
```

on address : '0x0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax'

Now I have created another contract to execute baz method.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract ResultUtil {
  function generateResult(address _foo, bytes _data) public {
   _foo.call(_data);   // call baz method.
  }
}
```

executing function generateResult("0x0aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax","0xcdcd77c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000450000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001");

function executed successfully but value of result remain 0

Comment: fyi, if I call function `(bytes4(sha3("baz(uint256,bool)")), 15, true)`, It is working successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked your function as `pure` which means it won't alter state. You can't alter state of a contract and return a value in one method. Use one method to change the state of the contract (not marked as `pure` or `view`) then use a different function to return the value (which WILL be `pure` or `view`).

See the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#view-functions) for more info on `pure` and `view` functions.

Comment: Thanks Adam, It just issue with pure. I hoping solidity team update their example from documents.